# Find the surface area of the solid of revolution.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, rotations, area

Find the surface area of the solid of revolution obtained by rotating the curve.
$$x= \sqrt{2y-y^2},\quad y\in\left[\frac{15}{16},\frac{25}{16}\right]$$

I get  $$A=\int 2\pi\sqrt{2y-y^2}\sqrt{\left(\frac{-1}{y(y-2)}\right)}\,dy$$ 
and I can't find a way to integrate it :(

Comment: There's a considerable algebraic simplification you haven't applied yet. :)

Comment: "Exercise" arclengths and surface areas tend to be very artificial. If you take almost any function and set up the integral, you will end up with an integral that cannot be expressed in elementary terms. But in most examples chosen for exercises, there is magical simplification.

Comment: @Eric Look inside the first radical, what do you see? Look in the denominator of the second radical. What do you see? Please put that negative from the numerator into the denominator and.....fireworks!!

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Here, to be fair, the surface is a sphere, and the magical simplification is particularly famous. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very nice simplification to this integral if we simply multiply the two radicals together. 
\begin{align*}
\int_{15/16}^{25/16}2\pi\sqrt{\frac{-(2y-y^2)}{y^2-2y}}\ \mathrm{d}y&=\int_{15/16}^{25/16} 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{y^2-2y}{y^2-2y}}\ \mathrm{d}y\\ &=\int_{15/16}^{25/16}2\pi \ \mathrm{d}y \\&=\bigg[2\pi y\bigg]_{15/16}^{25/16}\\&=\frac{50}{16}\pi-\frac{30}{16}\pi\\
&=\frac54\pi
\end{align*}